# Use Spring Integration to merge two files into a single file via SFTP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have two files in SFTP server which are large in size. I have one file in folder_A/A.txt. The second file is in folder_B/B.txt. I want to append contents of B.txt to A.txt and store them in folder_C/C.txt in SFTP server. One way is to download the files and read the content create new file and then upload the file to SFTP folder_C/C.txt . Is there any  efficient way to do this task using `SprinBoot` without actually downloading the files and do the same over network?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> template = new RemoteFileTemplate<>(sftpSessionFactory);
template.execute((SessionCallbackWithoutResult<LsEntry>) session -> {
    session.append(session.readRaw("folder_A/A.txt"), "folder_C/C.txt");
    session.append(session.readRaw("folder_B/B.txt"), "folder_C/C.txt");
});
```

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rft